# How to remove multiple divs from a webview by class and id?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying to remove multiple divs by class and by ID from a webview.

How can I do this?

This is what I have tried:

```
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('header-top')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('inchoo-socialconnect-login')[0].style.display='none';" +
                        "document.getElementById('before-footer')[0].style.display='none';" + "document.getElementById('footer')[0].style.display='none';" + "})()");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you only remove the first element that is found. The method getElementsByTagName returns a array, loop through all the elements rather than the  [0] element only to get things done.

Also i would recommend you call a javascript function in the webpage rather than printing entire function in webView.loadUrl